# Massive rename of files but keep the same sorting

Tags: bash, rename, puzzle

I have a lot of files in a folder with the same extension (e.g .vtk) and I am using a bash script to massive rename them with sequencial numbers. 
Here is the script i use:

```
n=0;
for file in *.vtk; do 
${file} 100_${n}.vtk;
n=$((n+1));
done
```

After the script's execution, all the files are rename like:

```
100_1.vtk
100_2.vtk
.
.
.
```

My problem is that I want to keep the sorting of files exactly the same as it was before. For example, if i had two sequential files named something.vtk and something_else.vtk, I want them after the renaming process, to correspond to 100_1.vtk and 100_2.vtk respectively.

Comment: Did you have a `mv` in your script?  Or just an echo to show what would happen?

Comment: The output of a glob lists the files in the default sorted order; it should happen automatically.  Are you sure you want to lose the extra information?  Also, do you need to worry about the sorting: `100_1.vtk`, `100_10.vtk`, `100_100.vtk`, `100_11.vtk`, `100_12.vtk`?  If so, the standard way to deal with that is adding leading zeroes.  The `printf` command can be used to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change your `for` loop from this:

```
 for file in *.vtk; do
```

to this:

```
 for file in $(ls -1 *.vtk | sort); do
```

If your filename don't contain spaces, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort -kX.Y! X refers to the column and Y to the character.
So, something like following should be fine:

```
$ ls | sort -k1.5
```